# IOS 6 screen rotation without using storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation

Anyone who's trying the newest iOS 6 beta(version 2 or 3) has the same experience of auto rotation not working?

I am not using storyboard but pure navigation control:

```
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
```

And have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: ](UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
} else {
    return YES;
}
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

BUT IOS has no espouse at all, works fine with all previous iOS on 3GS/4S and 4.3,5.0.5.1 simulator, but iOS 6 seems just buggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that:
Since my app is trying to support from 4.3+, I have to use the navigation controller to do every view switch.

by ios6 seems delegates to the navigation controller, I have to define my own navigation controller, and setup conditions and functions to change its rotation behaviour.

When I load a view, I then do([self.navigationCOntroller setEnableLandscape:(BOOL)false]). in that way  you have full controller of your navigation controller.

NOTE: I did try override the navigation controller methods, but seems just get ignored. (This only happens to ios 6.0 as well), haven't test 6.1 yet, so not sure if it's get fixed(which please let me know if it does)

Answer (score 10):

Autorotation is changing in iOS 6. In iOS 6, the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of `UIViewController` is deprecated. In its place, you should use the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` methods.

[Read more here](http://9to5mac.com/2012/06/25/apple-pushes-ios-6-0-update-to-devs/).

Comment: When is the shouldAutorotate function called?  It never seems to be called for me when I rotate the screen... Or maybe this is a problem with the simulator?

Comment: Check out my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape

Answer (score 7):

instead of `[self.window addSubview:navController.view];`

insert `self.window.rootViewController = navController;`

Comment: To increase the quality of your post please include how/why your answer will solve the problem.

Comment: You just saved my life. I tried everything else for the past 3 hours. I've been getting the callbacks, but iOS ignored everything I put there. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: This works when compiled on iOS6 sdk on iOS, but it does not work for me when compiled on iOS6 sdk ran on iOS5 os!
Did you try and look how it works on iOS5?

Comment: For iOS 5 it's ok also

Comment: @0x7fffffff : if you addsubview the controller.view in iOS6+, the rotation delegates won't pass. it's cleaner to set the rootviewcontroller of the window anyway

Comment: @Medhi Don't tell me, those are good details to add to your answer.